# Text input fields in flex when full screened does not work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

Hi all i have a problem where if my application is full screen i cannot click on any text input component and i cannot input any text into the fields. i have tried creating the text input fields at run time and i have tried creating them on the canvas when on the gui design window in flex builder. however they both give the same results and do not let me pick them and enter text. Any thoughts
Regards
Mark

Comment: i have just found out that in full screen mode it disables keyboard input which is a little crap to be honest. anyone got any idea of a way around this or if it has been corrected already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said in the comment (just writing this answer for anyone that stumbles across this question), the keyboard is disabled when you are in Full Screen Mode.

This is due to security restrictions, in that someone could build a swf that spoofs some action on your machine... for instance displaying a mimic desktop that has a dialogue up asking the user to enter their live ID and password.  There are probably loads of other sinister uses that adobe want to avoid by disabling keyboard input.  There is no way around this I'm afraid.

J

Comment: Note that the directional keys, the space bar and TAB are enabled in Flash Player 10 ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using AIR instead of Flex you can run in full-screen mode with full keyboard input enabled:

> Setting the displayState property of the Stage to StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE places the window in full-screen mode, and keyboard input is permitted in this mode. (In SWF content running in a browser, keyboard input is not permitted). To exit full-screen mode, the user presses the Escape key.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e06.html

Comment: my app needs to be online and to my understanding air does not run online. cheers anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

this will do
the above line of code is in action script 3
just add it to your code