# AS3 - fullscreen disables input field?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, fullscreen

I have made an application in AS3 that goes fullscreen.

in the application I have a settings panel where the user has some input fields which he can't manipulate, once I go fullscreen the user's ability to change those fields are gone, you can only select the text but not change it. Once we change back to the regular view of the application (in the browser) you can manipulate those settings again.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176639/text-input-fields-in-flex-when-full-screened-does-not-work

Comment: http://www.leebrimelow.com/flash-player-11-3-fullscreen-keyboard-input/